# How to fix - Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' : Unknown access type record - with Jpa and multiple reposirorys

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to map two tables together via a joining table in Spring using JPA and I keep getting the error - Error creating bean with name `entityManagerFactory` defined in class path resource `[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unknown access type record`.

I'm using Jpa and an H2 database.

The user class

```java
import java.util.List;

import com.JamesPooch.GameStratTracker.UserGame.UserGame;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 25, message = "Username length must be between 8 and 25 characters")
    private String username;
    @Size(min = 8, max = 25, message = "Password length must be between 8 and 25 characters")
    private String password;
    @Email(message = "Email must be valid")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_game_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<UserGame> userGame;
        
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

the userGame class

```java
import java.util.List;

import com.JamesPooch.GameStratTracker.Game.Game;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;

public class UserGame {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_game_id")
    private Integer userGameId;

    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "game_id")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Game> game;

    public List<Game> getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(List<Game> game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
}
```

The Game class

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "game_id")
    private Integer gameId;
    @Size(min=2, max = 100, message = "Game name must be between 2 and 100 characters")
    private String gameName;
    private String gameDescription;

    public String getGameName() {
        return gameName;
    }

    public void setGameName(String gameName) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
    }

    public String getGameDescription() {
        return gameDescription;
    }

    public void setGameDescription(String gameDescription) {
        this.gameDescription = gameDescription;
    }    
}
```

Application.properties is below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

build.gradle dependencies are below

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.29.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.12.Final'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    // implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

I tried to change the schema to be one user to many userGames and then a one to one from user games to games. I also tried doing a one to many from users to userGames and then a one to many from userGames to games. I have tried changing the table and key names to make sure they're not accidentally reserved keywords.

Comment: Solved the issue, Hibernate needed to be updated to 6.2.6.Final